Почему не отображается миниатюра изображения в VS code при установке расширения Image Preview?
в браузере картинка отображается, но в самом vs code нет миниатюры. Путь указывал с "/" и без него


<img src="/img/pictire.jpg" >
<img src="img/pictire.jpg" >



